# How to format label and input tags

Tags: html, css

In my project, I have a dialog div with four labels, four text input, one submit button and one shutdow button.

I want it appears like this:

```
AAAAAAAA:input text
BBBBBBBB:input text
CCCCCCCC:input text
DDDDDDDD:input text
  submit shutdown
```

But acturally, it does not appear format, it likes this:

```
AAAAAAAA:input text
 BBBBBBBB:
        input text
CCCCCCCC:input text
DDDDDDDD:
  submit  input text 
        shutdown
```

It is ugly, I don't want it like that.

Here is my css and html code:

```
<style> 
.addDiv{width:25%;height:20%;position:absolute;top:35%;left:35%;border:2px solid #ffffff;color:white;display:none;border-radius:15px;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);}
.firDiv{height:80%;width:100%}  
.firDiv label{float:left;margin-left:10%;margin-top:2%;width:20%}
.firDiv input{float:right;border:1px solid #99ccff;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.35);margin-right:10%;
                    margin-top:2%;color:white;width:45%}
.secDiv{height:20%;text-align:center;width:100%;margin-top:5%}
</style>


<div id="addCnt" class="addDiv">
<form action="mng.php?act=add&table=IDC" method="POST">
       <div class="firDiv"> 
        <label>AAAAAAA:</label><input type="text" name="prdSty"><br />
        <label>BBBBBBB:</label><input type="text" name="diffLvl"><br />
        <label>CCCCCCC:</label><input type="text" name="repTm"><br />
        <label>DDDDDDD:</label><input type="text" name="fixTm"><br />
       </div>
       <div class="secDiv">
        <input type="submit" value="add" /><input id="sdnBt" type="button" value="shutdown" >
       </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Who can help me?

Comment: why not just use a table?

Comment: From your screenshots, it looks like the whole problem is .addDiv is not wide enough.

Comment: If you don't want to use front-end frameworks like `Bootstrap,Materialize`, the you can try with `table` tag. Otherwise you can use `ul,li` tags with `bootstrap` to format your form components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be something like this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.firDiv label {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  float: left;
  width: 17%;
}

.firDiv .control {
  float: left;
  width: 83%;
}

.form-group {
  clear: both
}

.secDiv {
  margin-left: 16%;
  padding-top:10px;
  
}
```

```html
<form action="mng.php?act=add&table=IDC" method="POST">
  <div class="firDiv">
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label>AAAAAAA:</label>
      <div class='control'><input type="text" name="prdSty"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label>BBBBBBB:</label>
      <div class='control'><input type="text" name="prdSty"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label>CCCCCCCC:</label>
      <div class='control'><input type="text" name="prdSty"></div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group'>
      <label>DDDDDDDDD:</label>
      <div class='control'><input type="text" name="prdSty"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secDiv">
    <input type="submit" value="add" />
    <input id="sdnBt" type="button" value="shutdown">
  </div>
  
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to do here. First you have to clear the floats after the first Div completed. Second is apply float left to your input fields.

```
  .firDiv input{float:left;border:1px solid #99ccff;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.35);margin-right:10%;
                margin-top:2%;color:white;width:45%;}
  .secDiv{height:20%;text-align:center;width:100%;margin-top:10%; clear:both;}
```

I have applied `clear:both` in `secDiv` and `float:left` in `firDiv`.

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/gvcr7vfL/)

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/80njn65v/)

```
.secDiv input {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather try adding each input and label to their own div, something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ba0cL61b/5/

What this does is adds a div `.row` inside your `firDiv` div and inside the `.row` adds a div for your label and one for your input.  So it would look like this:

```
<div class="row">        

   <div class="label">
     <label>AAAAAAA:</label>
   </div>
   <div class="input">
     <input type="text" name="prdSty">         
   </div>

</div>
```

This is a bit easier to understand and style.